# How to serialize non primitive data using JAXB?

Tags: java, xml-parsing, jaxb, xml-serialization

I want to serialize an object using JAXB. My class definitions looks like this:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class MyClass{
     <<How do I annotate this one?>>
     private xyz_type xyz;
     @XmlElement(name = "unique")
     private int unique;
} 
public class xyz_type extends abc_type{
    private qwe_tpe qwe;
    public static final ert_type ARRAY = ert_type.ARRAY; 
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: And what is question? What goes wong? What you expect and what you get?

Comment: you can add an annotation like ```@XmlElement(name = "xyz", required = true)private xyz_type xyz;```

Comment: @GigaKokaia I get only primitive data type listed in my xml file.

Comment: @SanthoshKThadka I tried it , but it is not working.

Comment: Do you have getters for fields , you need to serialize?

Comment: you can try `@XmlAccessorType (
    value = AccessType.FIELD 
)`

Answer (score 0):

You need a customer XML adapter for marshalling complex data types.

See this guide: https://www.baeldung.com/jaxb - 6. Complex Data Types